# Request URL formatting

Tags: objective-c, http, url, request

I am developing an iPhone application from where I need to be able to post a new topic in Yahoo finance message boar at http://messages.finance.yahoo.com/mb/KERX. How do I format the request URL? PLease xcuse my ignorence m very new in this kind of work. I just need the base url to use and the method that will post my topic to the message board.

Comment: Answer depends on the programming language you're using to fire HTTP requests. Please update your question and tags to include the programming language in question.

Comment: Thanks, M using objective c. My problem is formatting the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Api](http://developer.yahoo.com/) might help you.